# Refill fields in add/edit form after post

Tags: php, forms, field, fill

Im stuck on something related to forms and i wanna a solution terribly .

I have an add/edit form , sometimes the user gets an error message with reloading the form , so i wanna to keep pre-filled fields filled with the values , while in edit i want to keep the real value , here is what i mean :

```
<input type="text" name="meta[5]" value="<?php if(isset($itemDetails['Model'])) { echo $itemDetails['Model'];  } ?>"/>
```

Here in add it will be null while in edit it will fetch the value , so i want to do this with keeping fields pre-filled values after post , i'm saving the filled value as following :

```
$session['key_for_this_field']
```

I tried many solutions , one of it is the following while nothing works :

```
<input type="text" name="meta[5]" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['meta[5]']) ? $session['key_for_this_field']  : '' ?>"/>
```

Your help is highly appreciated .

Comment: If you reformat your question with proper grammar, spelling, and code snippets, The StackOverflow community can help you better.

Comment: Im trying to do , just moments

Comment: @Obida, I posted a working solution. By the way that is not the kind of value you would want to save on sessions.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say your form passes DATA with POST to your system.

You can add values to your HTML like so:

`<input id="firstName" type="text" maxlength="30" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['firstName'])) echo $_POST['firstName']?>">`

**If you look closely you can see that I have added the value attribute to the HTML which will be the value when the browser reloads.**

**This will only work if you POST the data to the same page!**

P.S. This is the only way (HTML & PHP ONLY, OF COURSE JS IS ALSO AVAILABLE).

Good Luck!

Comment: Yes it passes data with "POST" while this solution is not working :(

Comment: Do you pass it to the same page?

Comment: I pass it to a controller , while i validate some fields , so if there is an error validated fields , i reload the form with a message error , so i lost fields pre-filled values , the form used for add/edit .

Comment: So the default value should be the value fetched from the storage , while im using a session solution to check the value when posting .

Comment: Can you post then more of your code? Are you using session correctly? this is not a sign-up form I understand?

Comment: Yes its not a sign-up form , its for adding/editing items .

Yes i'm setting a session value for every field in controller and its correctly storing the values , while i can invest this way to set the value of fields .

Comment: It looks like you need either to add more code to the question or to work on your debugging skills

Comment: Ok i'll show you a text input as example : 

<input type="text" name="meta[5]" value="<?php if(isset($itemDetails['Model'])) { echo $itemDetails['Model'];  } ?>"/> 

Here the field will be filled with correct value in editing case , so lets suppose that in adding , the user added a value then got an validating error after post which will be redirected to the form , so after post in the controller to save the filled values im using session , but how to implement that in input value to keep editing value if its in edit case or the session value ??

Comment: When using a `textarea`, enter `<?php if(isset($_POST['var'])) echo $_POST['var']?>` between the opening and closing tag.